# dotnet run fails when run from System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: macos, process, f#

So I'm sure I'm doing something silly wrong. I'm not sure what it is.

If I run the following command from terminal everything works fine.

```
~>dotnet run --project /path/to/my.fsproj
```

However, when I run that command from an fsx file with the below code, I get an error.

```
let dotnetRunNoArgs path =
    let info = ProcessStartInfo(FileName = "dotnet", Arguments = sprintf "run --project %s " path )
    let proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(StartInfo = info)
    start proc
    proc

let buildProcessStartInfoFCollectionTests = 
    dotnetRunNoArgs "/path/to/my.fsproj"

buildProcessStartInfoFCollectionTests.Start() |> ignore
```

Error:

```
/Users/username/.nuget/packages/fsharp.net.sdk/1.0.0/build/FSharp.NET.Core.Sdk.targets(122,9): 
error MSB4062: The "Fsc" task could not be loaded from the assembly 
/Users/username/.nuget/packages/fsharp.compiler.tools/4.1.0/build/netcoreapp1.0/FSharp.Build.dll. 
Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/path/to/my.fsproj] 
/Users/username/.nuget/packages/fsharp.net.sdk/1.0.0/build/FSharp.NET.Core.Sdk.targets(122,9): 
error MSB4062: The "Fsc" task could not be loaded from the assembly 
/Users/username/.nuget/packages/fsharp.compiler.tools/4.1.0/build/netcoreapp1.0/FSharp.Build.dll. 
Assembly with same name is already loaded Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [/path/to/my.fsproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the [`CurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) first?

Comment: On Windows I've had issues running some programs directly as processes. I've had to start `cmd` instead and pass the actual executable as an argument. I'm not sure if that's any help!

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox this is an OS X environment

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I could tell it wasn't Windows, but maybe there's a common reason in both OS's that results in different behaviour when calling an executable directly vs through a shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ended up being in the fsproj file.

The problem was that it needed to have version attributes on

```
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0"/>
```

Also, I needed to remove `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"` from the project tag.